# Unable to access my phpMyadmin (MAMP)

Tags: mysql, server, mamp

I am trying to access my databases through phpMyAdmin yet I am not able to get through because of this error.

```
Warning in ./libraries/session.inc.php#101
session_start():

open(/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/sess_aa5d7e3be7359a8d42a83552c915744058e34fe8, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Backtrace

./libraries/session.inc.php#101: session_start()
./libraries/common.inc.php#349: require(./libraries/session.inc.php)
./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```

Comment: here is the Screenshot http://nimb.ws/wnlzxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/` does not exists on your system, but your PHP installation tries to save the session files in this directory. You have to create the directory so the PHP installation can save the session files or you can change the [`session.save_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) setting to save the session files in a different directory. Keep in mind that the PHP installation needs write permissions on the choosen directory.